# Assembly MIPS. How change the content of two positions of vector?

Tags: assembly, vector, mips, mars-simulator

What I want:
    Example:
            v[0] = 5
            v[1] = 10
            after...
            v[0] = 10
            v[1] = 5

Apparently everything works, but when we will print the content, only the content of $s0 print the correct value.
If you try print the content of the saver $s2 one error appears:
"Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x00000000"                             . Can someone help-me?
Thanks very much

```
.data
vector : .word 5,10

.text

la $s0, vector
la $s1, vector
add $s1, $s1, 4



# $s0 is v[0]
# $s1 is v[1]
# $s2 is the saver

lw $s2, 0($s1)
sw $s0, 0($s1)
sw $s2, 0($s0)

li $v0, 1
lw $a0, 0($s0)
syscall

li $v0, 1
lw $a0, 0($s1)
syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your swap is incorrect. What you're doing with `sw $s0, 0($s1)` is storing the address of one of the elements, not storing the value of that element. So you need to do something like this instead:

```
lw $s2, 0($s0)
lw $s3, 0($s1)
sw $s2, 0($s1)
sw $s3, 0($s0)
```

Secondly, you're not terminating your program properly. At the end of your code you should execute the `exit` syscall:

```
li $v0, 10    # syscall_exit
syscall
```

And if you want a space or newline between the numbers you'll have to print one using syscall 4 or 11.